# How to hide elements when Hamburger menu is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm having problems with my mobile responsive navbar. It works perfectly on desktop but on mobile, it is showing like this

[image: Image 01]

So I tried removing the code that play video in the background and it worked! This is my navbar code,

```js
var navList = document.getElementById("nav-lists");

var body = body;

function Show() {
  navList.classList.add("_Menus-show");

}

function Hide() {
  navList.classList.remove("_Menus-show");

}
```

```css
<style>*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .logo {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .logo a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
}

.container .logo a img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 60px;
}

.container .navbar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container .navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.9);
}

.container .navbar ul .close {
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul .close span {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .navbar .icon-bar {
  padding: 18px 8px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .navbar .icon-bar i {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 2px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .container {
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .container .logo {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .container .navbar {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0;
    flex: 0;
  }
  .container .navbar ul {
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    position: fixed;
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-transition: left .3s;
    -o-transition: left .3s;
    transition: left .3s;
  }
  .container .navbar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #555555;
  }
  .container .navbar ul .close {
    display: block;
  }
  .container .navbar .icon-bar {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .container .navbar ._Menus-show {
    left: 0;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width:875px) {
    .navbar.responsive {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: rgba(236, 201, 205, 1);
      transition: background-color .6s;
      .top-hero.display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">

    <div class="icon-bar" onclick="Show()">
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
    </div>

    <ul id="nav-lists">
      <li class="close"><span onclick="Hide()">×</span></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>

Here's the code that makes navbar not working and make the video as the background is,

<div class="top-hero" id="hero">
  <div class="video-background">
    <div class="video-foreground">
      <div class="_16-9-desktop_9-16-mobile">
        <iframe id="topHeroVideo" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/461295222?background=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet made you into a [mcve]

Comment: Please add expected behaviour, what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```js
var navList = document.getElementById("nav-lists");

var body = body;

function Show() {
  navList.classList.add("_Menus-show");

}

function Hide() {
  navList.classList.remove("_Menus-show");

}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .logo {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .logo a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
}

.container .logo a img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 60px;
}

.container .navbar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container .navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.9);
}

.container .navbar ul .close {
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul .close span {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .navbar .icon-bar {
  padding: 18px 8px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .navbar .icon-bar i {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 2px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .container {
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .container .logo {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .container .navbar {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0;
    flex: 0;
  }
  .container .navbar ul {
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    position: fixed;
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-transition: left .3s;
    -o-transition: left .3s;
    transition: left .3s;
  }
  .container .navbar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #555555;
  }
  .container .navbar ul .close {
    display: block;
  }
  .container .navbar .icon-bar {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .container .navbar ._Menus-show {
    left: 0;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width:875px) {
    .navbar.responsive {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: rgba(236, 201, 205, 1);
      transition: background-color .6s;
      .top-hero.display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">

    <div class="icon-bar" onclick="Show()">
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
    </div>

    <ul id="nav-lists">
      <li class="close"><span onclick="Hide()">×</span></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>

Everthing is working fine, So where is the issue?
<div class="top-hero" id="hero">
  <div class="video-background">
    <div class="video-foreground">
      <div class="_16-9-desktop_9-16-mobile">
        <iframe id="topHeroVideo" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/461295222?background=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks, answering! I also have the question what's the issue and I'm sure it's something with the part that I commented. Once it's been removed, it works fine.